# How to convert an xml into a json using gson library

Tags: java, json, xml, gson

I have to convert a XML using gson library into a JSON

i haven´t found how to do it using gson library(java)

Comment: Gson isn't going to help you with XML. You'd have better luck with Jackson

Comment: Otherwise, you'd have to parse your XML into valid Java objects using some other library (such as Jackson)  then simply use Gson to write them out.

Comment: Underscore-java library has static method U.xmlToJson(xmlstring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Jackson to do this:

import these libraries:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

then do this in your class:

```
    public class Example {
        private String name;
        private int number;
    }
    Example example = new XmlMapper().readValue(xml, Example.class);
    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(example);
```